# does bookings api support "Resource owner password credentials" type of access token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to use azure application owner's user account and password to access bookings api, for example https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses, and I got the unspecified error.

can anyone please explain what does this error mean?

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3140b289-3547-4198-84c1-7035e51ea438",
            "date": "2019-06-26T08:45:59"
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#bookingBusinesses",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "test@mytest.com.au",
            "displayName": "booking-test"
        }
    ]
}
```

----------I have enabled public client setting in auzre application
[image: setting page]

[image: error message from post man test]

--------- my code to get resource owner credential access token and call booking api with sdk beta
[image: code to gain access token]

[image: code to create graphclient]

[image: code to call booking api]

Comment: Hi could you please provide some more information like  `1.which subscription you are using?` and `2. what kind of user email you are using in ROPC to get access token?` as well as `3.what kind of permission did you assign for that?`

Comment: Hi have tried that one?

Answer (score 0):

According to my test your error might happen due to following reason:

1. If you don't have `Office 365 Business Premium subscription`
2. If you don't have `Bookings.Read.All` dedicated permission
3. If you are trying with `personal Microsoft account`

**Note:** Make sure you have done above steps accordingly.

**Further Reference:** 
If you need more details you could have look on official docs below reference.

1. [Prerequisite for Booking API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/booking-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta#using-the-bookings-rest-api)
2. [Permissions required for Booking API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs#permissions)
3. [Git Hub Link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/booking-api-overview.md#using-the-bookings-rest-api)